# mysqldump pipe gzip speed differences

Tags: gzip, pipe, mysql

I'm piping the result of mysqldump to gzip, the speed of gzip seems to lag behind greatly

```
gzip: 34.9MiB 0:01:54 [ 218kiB/s] 
mysqldump:  735MiB 0:01:54 [5.73MiB/s]
```

2 questions:
1. would this eventually break the pipe if gzip can't catch up?  does pipe hold all these data in memory?

2. how would I speedup gzip(already know about -9 vs -1 compression options)?

Answer (score 2):

GZIP is CPU-bound. So you can lower the compression rate as you said, but you won't gain much speed. Try to poke around LZO, which is a lot faster (compression rate is not as good, but I find it to be a good trade off)

You can find a good benchmark here: http://stephane.lesimple.fr/blog/2010-07-20/lzop-vs-compress-vs-gzip-vs-bzip2-vs-lzma-vs-lzma2xz-benchmark-reloaded.html

As for your first question, the OS will do the buffering for youm you don't have to worry about it. Even if your RAM isn't big enough, the buffering will write to disk but GZIP will still be slower.

Comment: According to the man page of pipe, the pipe will not write to disk in this case. Instead it will block the writing process mysqldump. See: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html

Answer (score 0):

As for speeding up gzip, you could try [pigz](http://zlib.net/pigz), which uses multiple processors/cores.